# Can I use spannear in the nested field for different block in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, search-engine

The document is like:

```
doc = {  
  "id": 1,  
  "content": [  
    {  
      "txt": I,  
      "time": 0,  
    },  
    {  
      "txt": have bla bla,  
      "time": 1,  
    },  
    {  
      "txt": bla bla book,  
      "time": 2,  
    },  
    {  
      "txt": do not match this block,  
      "time": 3,  
    },  
  ]  
}
```

And the search query is like:

```
"span_near": {
    "clauses": [
        {"span_term": {"content.txt": "I"}},
        {"span_term": {"content.txt": "book"}},
    ],
    "slop": 5,
    "in_order": False,
}
```

And I want to return "content.time": [0,1,2]

Now, I know by using the nested field, the "content.time" can be retrieved, but it seems like the "content.txt" is separated between each block. And I want to search for the entire "content.txt" like a flattened structure, but still can return the matching "content.time". Is there anyone know how to achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: `[nested] query does not support [span_near]`, can you please share your expected search result ?

Comment: The expected search result is like matching "content.txt" for "I have bla bla bla bla book" and return the matching "content.time": [0,1,2].

Comment: Can you share your mapping for this structure? is `content` of `nested` type?

Comment: Hi I don't know whether I should use nested or flattened type if I want to get the matching "content.time".